# How to resolve a foreign key reference when persisting an entity with dropwizard?

Tags: json, hibernate, jackson, deserialization, dropwizard

Say I have a student entity:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  @Getter
  @JsonProperty
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Getter
  @JsonProperty
  @ManyToOne
  private Clazz clazz;

  @Getter
  @JsonProperty
  private String
        firstName,
        lastName;
}
```

And I want to persist it by POSTing to a JAX-RS class:

```
@Path("/student")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public class StudentResource {
  private StudentDAO studentDao;

  public StudentResource(StudentDAO studentDao) {
    this.studentDao = studentDao;
  }

  @POST
  @UnitOfWork
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void persist(Student student) {
    this.studentDao.save(student);
  }
}
```

And my request body looks like:

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Bloggs",
  "clazz": 1
}
```

Then Jackson's going to blow up because:

```
DEBUG [2015-05-16 11:08:59,144] io.dropwizard.jersey.jackson.JsonProcessingExceptionMapper: Unable to process JSON
! com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Clazz] from Integral number (1); no single-int-arg constructor/factory method
```

I understand *why* I'm getting this error; it can't deserialize the Clazz object from the key. I can't think of a few hacky ways to fix this (e.g. add a Clazz(int id) constructor and make the clazzDao statically available). But can someone offer me a cleaner solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Kennedy points out on the dropwizard mailing list, the obvious solution is not to use the same dto-style objects for REST as in the persistence layer. Then it's trivial to receive the REST object within StudentResource and convert to one I can persist.